# Copper to CPVC transition fittings : allowed by code to be used inside a wall?

Tags: plumbing, copper, cpvc

Does the Uniform Plumbing Code (US) allow copper-to-CPVC transition fittings to be used inside a wall?  Just to be clear, I'm referring to the hybrid fittings that are part brass, part CPVC.

[image: Copper-to-CPVC transition fitting]

Comment: Whose plumbing code?

Comment: Sorry, edited.  UPC

Answer (score 1):

The code does not specify specifically that such joints cannot be inside of a wall.

[image: UPC code section 605]